# How to change background color of an input field with conditionals in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to change the background color of the input field with an if statement. I dont know why it isnt working. What can I do to get it working?

```js
function increment() {

  var textbox = document.
  getElementById("inc");
  textbox.value++;
}

var inputfield = document.getElementById("inc")


// trying to change bg color of inputfield if number higher or lower -- doesnt work yet 
if (inputfield.value > 3) {
  inputfield.style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
}
```

```html
  <div class = wrapper>

    <button onclick="increment()">Click to + 1!</button>

    <input class="inputfield" id="inc" type="text" value="0" />

  </div>
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more code; if `inputfield` is an `HTMLInputElement` the code shown should work (although `inputfield.value` is a string, it should be coerced to a number).

Comment: Add an event listener and make the check and add/remove a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your javascript `function increment()` gets executed each click of the button, the rest of your javascript code gets only executed once after the document has been loaded. Initially input field `#inc` value is `0` and will not change color as it never becomes `> 3` this way.

In your Javascript:

- you only have to get the reference to input element `#inc` once (`const textBox`) and use that in your increment function. In the snippet I defined the *constant* `textBox` as *global* because the reference does not change, just its `.value`. Consequently method `.getElementById` does not have to be executed each click of the button.
- After the button has been clicked, increment `textBox.value` and change the color when the value `> 3`.

**Snippet**

```js
// Get a reference to the textbox
const textbox = document.getElementById("inc");

function increment() {
    textbox.value++; // increment its value

    if (textbox.value > 3) {
        // change its color
        textbox.style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>
    <button onclick="increment()">Click to + 1!</button>
    <input class="inputfield" id="inc" type="text" value="0" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

We can start of by grabbing the input element from the DOM.

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');
```

Once we have the element to work with we can, we can add an event listener (blur) so whenever a user moves out of the box the action in the code will be performed.
JS:

```
const input = document.getElementById("input");
input.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  if (input.value.length > 3) {
    input.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input" />
```

Comment: Please don't answer bad questions with guesses. Stack Overflow is trying to make a library of high quality questions and answers. Let the OP update their question with more information if/when they decide to.

Comment: My code is not a guess. It is a performant and working solution lol.

Comment: You're guessing as to what the OP is struggling with. Their code already works as is with the caveats I've given. Also, the code in this answer checks the length of the value, not the value itself, which is what the OP says they want: "If the value of the input field is higher than 3 I want to change bg color to red."

Comment: Okay I get what you are saying. Makes sense now.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out.

```js
const inputfield = document.getElementById("change_color_example")

inputfield.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  if (this.value > 3) {
    this.classList.add("active-math")
  } else {
    this.classList.remove("active-math")
  }

  if (this.value.length > 3) {
    this.classList.add("active-length")
  } else {
    this.classList.remove("active-length")
  }
})
```

```css
.example-input {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.example-input.active-math {
  color: #f8f8f8;
  background-color: #AA0000;
}

.example-input.active-length {
  color: blue;
  background-color: bisque;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="change_color_example" class="example-input" />
```

Comment: Please don't answer bad questions with guesses. Stack Overflow is trying to make a library of high quality questions and answers. Let the OP update their question with more information if/when they decide to. Also, "Check this out" is a poor explanation of code.